# Allow to hide not interesting question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

This Q&A sites contains a lot of questions. We "filter" them by tags, but we are *not interested* in every question belonging to the tag.

I mean, maybe there are bad questions, maybe there are time-consuming questions or we may not be able to answer the question at all.

Wouldn't it be nice if we could *manually hide* **uninteresting** question from the lists? Or at least *mark them as read*? **Question by question not by tag.**

For example, let's say someone posted a question about a feature that you don't know, even if it is a feature of one of your favorite technologies, then you may not want to see that particular question anymore in the list. So it is **uninteresting** to you.

Comment: Meh, that's something for an add-on. Not the main site functionality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what you mean?

Comment: There's already a feature that allows you to show them in a faded manner (not hiding).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean question by question not by tag.

Comment: @king.code: that this is not something I want the Stack Exchange devs to spend time on. Use a userscript instead, and post it on http://stackapps.com/ to share.

Comment: @king.code And how the system should detect, what you consider a _bad/uninteresting question_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want manually mark the bad question as read.

Comment: I see there *already* is such a userscript: [Hide unwanted questions (Greasemonkey Script)](http://stackapps.com/q/4166)

Comment: @king.code I don't do so. If the title or the co tags don't interest me, I just don't read it. I can't get what you're bothering about.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just don't want to read them again and again every time I refresh the list. I want to keep the list clean.

Comment: How do you define "uninteresting" in terms that can be implemented as computer code?

Comment: @GordonM I mean let's say someone post a question about a feature of, in your case PHP, then you may don't want to see that particular question anymore in the list. So it is not interestig to you. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @GordonM sorry: a feature that you hypothetically don't know.

Comment: My browser marks links as visited. I hardly ever read a question twice, unless some cheat changes the title.

Answer (score 6):

You can install a userscript to do just this:

### [Hide unwanted questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/4166/hide-unwanted-questions-greasemonkey-script)

This kind of 'power user' functionality should be done exactly like that, in add-on user scripts, leaving the site itself uncluttered and free of too many knobs and twiddles and leaving the Stack Exchange developers free to focus on more important issues, such as ways to keep the crap from being posted in the first place.

Comment: It didn't work to me. Anyway I didn't know about this way of enhancing.

Comment: @king.code: there may be others; I didn't do an extensive search in any case.